# Jquery with Sitecore Page editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, sitecore, sitecore-dms, page-editor

I need to put span tags around first word in a line. I used the below Jquery which is working fine in sitecore standard mode.

```
$("body").has(".widget h2").addClass("standard-mode");
$("body").has(".scLoadingIndicatorInner").removeClass("standard-mode").addClass("page-edit");


$('.standard-mode .widget h2').html(function(i, html){
    return html.replace(/(\w+\s)/, '<span>$1</span>')
})
```

When i first load the page editor this works fine as well(by not inserting the span tags), but when i created a multivariate test switching between the A/B by using arrow marks shows like inserting the span tags which it should not suppose to do as it is in page-edit mode but it does and breaking the html as below.

```
<h2>
        &lt;<span>input </span>id="fld_D26C954B73BE4C62B6F25BE191A86F18_7B55B5E5EDD84D4E88B16C6E073495A5_en_1_0e80a9c63ab6419f8135b70511e892f1_16487" class="scFieldValue" name="fld_D26C954B73BE4C62B6F25BE191A86F18_7B55B5E5EDD84D4E88B16C6E073495A5_en_1_0e80a9c63ab6419f8135b70511e892f1_16487" type="hidden" value="Badger Cull"&gt;<span class="scChromeData">{"commands":[{"click":"chrome:common:edititem({command:\"webedit:open\"})","header":"Edit the related item","icon":"/temp/IconCache/SoftwareV2/16x16/cubes_blue.png","disabledIcon":"/temp/cubes_blue_disabled16x16.png","isDivider":false,"tooltip":"Edit this item in the Content Editor.","type":"common"},{"click":"chrome:rendering:personalize({command:\"webedit:personalize\"})","header":"Personalize","icon":"/temp/IconCache/PeopleV2/16x16/users3_edit.png","disabledIcon":"/temp/users3_edit_disabled16x16.png","isDivider":false,"tooltip":"Personalize component.","type":"sticky"},{"click":"javascript:Sitecore.PageModes.PageEditor.postRequest('ActiveISPageEditor:publish(id={D26C954B-73BE-4C62-B6F2-5BE191A86F18})',null,false)","header":"Publish the related item","icon":"/temp/IconCache/Network/16x16/download.png","disabledIcon":"/temp/download_disabled16x16.png","isDivider":false,"tooltip":"Publish this item.","type":"common"},{"click":"chrome:rendering:editvariations({command:\"webedit:editvariations\"})","header":"Edit variations","icon":"/temp/IconCache/SoftwareV2/16x16/breakpoints.png","disabledIcon":"/temp/breakpoints_disabled16x16.png","isDivider":false,"tooltip":"Edit the variations.","type":"sticky"}],"contextItemUri":"sitecore://master/{D26C954B-73BE-4C62-B6F2-5BE191A86F18}?lang=en&amp;ver=1","custom":{},"displayName":"Header Text","expandedDisplayName":null}</span><span scfieldtype="single-line text" sc_parameters="prevent-line-break=true" contenteditable="false" class="scWebEditInput scEnabledChrome" id="fld_D26C954B73BE4C62B6F25BE191A86F18_7B55B5E5EDD84D4E88B16C6E073495A5_en_1_0e80a9c63ab6419f8135b70511e892f1_16487_edit" sc-part-of="field">Badger Cull</span>
    </h2>
```

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can check the JavaScript property `Sitecore.PageModes.PageEditor` to see if you are in page editor mode and can disable your javascript accordingly.

```
function isPageEditor() {
    if (typeof Sitecore == "undefined") {
        return false;
    }
    if (typeof Sitecore.PageModes == "undefined" || Sitecore.PageModes == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return Sitecore.PageModes.PageEditor != null;
}

if (isPageEditor() == false) {
    //do your stuff here   
}
```

Comment: +1 And all this time I've been setting a css class on the body and disabling that way! Great info.

Comment: Sorry i am not expert in javascript, after I use the above code I end up with the error 
ReferenceError: Sitecore is not defined
if (Sitecore == null) {

Comment: I tried the solution you provided, its working fine in normal mode and page editor mode, but when i try to switch control for Multivariate testing it still inserting span tags, which should not as it is in page editor mode? any suggestions?

Comment: This helped me with Sitecore 8.1 in which we needed to load a Marketo form but was failing while editing in the EE.